# Search String in Spreadsheet and Highlight

Tags: excel, vba, search

I am using VBA in excel to use Sheet 2's list of string values and query Sheet 1's data to see if Sheet 2's values exist. If they exist, highlight the cells in Sheet1.

The listing I have in Sheet 2 is as follows:

COLUMN A

**Admin Services**

**executives**

**firewall**'

**generator**

**internet**

**IT Application Support**

**proxy**

**remedy**

My VBA is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

row_num = 1

Query = Sheet2.Range("A:A")

While Trim(ActiveCell.Value) <> ""

row_num = row_num + 1
    item_sum = Sheet1.Range("B" & row_num)
    item_note = Sheet1.Range("C" & row_num)
    item_group = Sheet1.Range("E" & row_num)

        If (InStr(item_sum, Query) Or InStr(item_note, Query) Or InStr(item_group, Query)) Then

            ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

        End If

Wend


End Sub
```

Right now I have no error flags and nothing highlights. I tried using Query value for Sheet 2's column A but I am not sure if it is working.

[image]

Update:

I tried changing the While loop to:

```
Do
DoEvents
row_num = row_num + 1
    item_sum = Sheet1.Range("B" & row_num)
    item_note = Sheet1.Range("C" & row_num)
    item_group = Sheet1.Range("E" & row_num)

        If (InStr(item_sum, Query) Or InStr(item_note, Query) Or InStr(item_group, Query)) Then

            ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

        End If

Loop Until item_sum = ""
```

but my highlighting did the following:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps it works better when you load the values you need to check against into an array, and then check the array for matches. Did you also declare your variables?

Comment: Not sure what you mean "load the values" but I assume you mean `If (InStr(item_sum, "Remedy")) Then` . Also, I realize my Sheet1 name is Data and Sheet2 name is List. So I tried `item_sum = Worksheets("Data").Range("B" & row_num)` and still the ActiveCell will only highlight where cursor left off not based on string query @Luuklag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code works just fine. The only problem is that you are not highlighting the cell which is being checked but the `ActiveCell`. So, you might want to consider changing that to something like this:

```
Option Base 0
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim item_sum, item_note, item_group As String
Dim lngRowNumber As Long
Dim varFound As Variant
Dim rngQuery As Range

Set rngQuery = Sheet2.Range("A:A")
lngRowNumber = 1

Do
    If Trim(item_sum) = vbNullString Then Exit Do
    ' Go to the next row
    lngRowNumber = lngRowNumber + 1
    ' Get the data to look for
    item_sum = Sheet1.Range("B" & lngRowNumber).Value2
    item_note = Sheet1.Range("C" & lngRowNumber).Value2
    item_group = Sheet1.Range("E" & lngRowNumber).Value2
    ' Check the item_sum
    Set varFound = rngQuery.Find(item_sum, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not varFound Is Nothing Then
        Sheet1.Range("B" & lngRowNumber).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        Set varFound = Nothing
    End If
    ' Check the item_note
    Set varFound = rngQuery.Find(item_note, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not varFound Is Nothing Then
        Sheet1.Range("C" & lngRowNumber).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        Set varFound = Nothing
    End If
    ' Check the item_group
    Set varFound = rngQuery.Find(item_group, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not varFound Is Nothing Then
        Sheet1.Range("E" & lngRowNumber).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        Set varFound = Nothing
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Obviously, I also made some minor changes to the overall code. Hope some of them are helpful.

Comment: My Sheet names where "Data" for Sheet1 and "List" for Sheet2 but I changed them back to Sheet1 and Sheet2. With your change, it looks like nothing is highlighting. However I now get a type mismatch with line `If (InStr(item_sum, Query) Or InStr(item_note, Query) Or InStr(item_group, Query)) Then`

Comment: Ok so when I remove the `Query` and hardcode one of the words to `InStr(item_sum, "Remedy"))` it works. Issue is my sheet2 list will increase from time to time so I don't want hardcoded strings

Comment: I will ask a separate question for my issue. Thanks!