# Type Mismatch Error for Sheet2.Range String Search

Tags: excel, search, vba

Following my previous question 
[Search String in Spreadsheet and Highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516247/search-string-in-spreadsheet-and-highlight/31518401#31518401), I was able to get the cells to highlight in VBA for excel. My VBA code searches the sheet to find specific words and highlight the cells that contain those words.

My issue is that when I try and make a list to search on, I get a `type mismatch error`. So my "array" list of values to query on in my Sheet 2 flags an error.

Sheet 2 list:

[image]

If I hardcode my search strings it works though.

**Therefore, how do I make my array list work in my following code in place of the `"Remedy"/"Internet ..etc"` in `(InStr(item_sum, "Remedy"))` and so forth?**

My hardcoded strings in my code is as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Query = Sheet2.Range("A:A")

Do
DoEvents

row_num = row_num + 1
Sheet1.Range("B" & row_num & ":E" & row_num).Interior.Color = xlNone

    item_sum = Sheet1.Range("B" & row_num)
    item_note = Sheet1.Range("C" & row_num)
    item_group = Sheet1.Range("E" & row_num)

        If (InStr(item_sum, "Remedy")) Then
            Sheet1.Range("B" & row_num).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        End If

        If (InStr(item_sum, "Internet") Or InStr(item_sum, "internet")) Then
            Sheet1.Range("B" & row_num).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        End If

        If InStr(item_note, "Remedy") Then
            Sheet1.Range("C" & row_num).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        Else
            Sheet1.Range("C" & row_num).Interior.Color = xlNone
        End If

        If InStr(item_group, "Remedy") Then
            Sheet1.Range("D" & row_num).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        End If

Loop Until item_sum = ""


End Sub
```

As you can see I tried the line : `Query = Sheet2.Range("A:A")` and searched like so : `If (InStr(item_sum, Query)) Then` but it didn't work.

**UPDATE:**

So I have been playing with dynamic name. So far I got the strings from Sheet2's list to display in a MsgBox to debug. However, when it runs it will highlight B2 cell that shows "Remedy" but nothing else. I can tell however that my `UCase(Sheet2.Range("A" & Count).Value)` displays each one in the list. Still only colors B2 cell? When I decode line by line it seems to only register the last string search in Sheet2's list which is "Remedy" and thus only highlights B2.

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

row_num = 1

Dim query_list As Range
Set query_list = Sheet2.Range("A:A")

'MsgBox "Number of Rows are " & WorksheetFunction.CountA(query_list)
list_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(query_list)

row_num = row_num + 1
Sheet1.Range("B" & row_num & ":E" & row_num).Interior.Color = xlNone
Sheet1.Range("I" & row_num).Value = ""

item_sum = Sheet1.Range("B" & row_num)
item_note = Sheet1.Range("C" & row_num)
item_group = Sheet1.Range("E" & row_num)

For Each list In query_list

Count = Count + 1
If (Count <= list_count) Then
        'ALL QUERIES FOR COLUMN B

        MsgBox UCase(Sheet2.Range("A" & Count).Value)
        If (InStr(UCase(item_sum), UCase(Sheet2.Range("A" & Count).Value))) Then
            Sheet1.Range("B" & row_num).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            Sheet1.Range("I" & row_num).Value = "Yes"
        End If
End If

Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIGURED IT OUT!

What I needed to do was get row count in Sheet2 and use that to update the string value in line `(InStr(UCase(item_group), UCase(Sheet2.Range("A" & Count).Value)))`

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

row_num = 1

Dim query_list As Range
Set query_list = Sheet2.Range("A:A")

Dim total_rows As Integer
total_rows = WorksheetFunction.CountA(query_list)
MsgBox total_rows

'MsgBox "Number of Rows are " & WorksheetFunction.CountA(query_list)
Dim list_count As Integer
list_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(query_list)

Do
DoEvents

            row_num = row_num + 1
            Sheet1.Range("B" & row_num & ":E" & row_num).Interior.Color = xlNone
            Sheet1.Range("I" & row_num).Value = ""

            'MsgBox row_num
            item_sum = Sheet1.Range("B" & row_num)
            item_note = Sheet1.Range("C" & row_num)
            item_group = Sheet1.Range("E" & row_num)
            Count = 1

            While (Count <= list_count)
            'MsgBox Count
            'MsgBox item_sum
                If (InStr(UCase(item_sum), UCase(Sheet2.Range("A" & Count).Value))) Then
                'MsgBox Count
                'MsgBox UCase(Sheet2.Range("A" & Count).Value)
                    Sheet1.Range("B" & row_num).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                    Sheet1.Range("I" & row_num).Value = "Yes"

                End If

                Count = Count + 1
                'MsgBox Count

            Wend

            Count = 1
            While (Count <= list_count)
            'MsgBox Count
            'MsgBox item_sum
                If (InStr(UCase(item_note), UCase(Sheet2.Range("A" & Count).Value))) Then
                'MsgBox Count
                'MsgBox UCase(Sheet2.Range("A" & Count).Value)
                    Sheet1.Range("C" & row_num).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                    Sheet1.Range("I" & row_num).Value = "Yes"

                End If

                Count = Count + 1
                'MsgBox Count

            Wend

            Count = 1

            While (Count <= list_count)
            'MsgBox Count
            'MsgBox item_sum
                If (InStr(UCase(item_group), UCase(Sheet2.Range("A" & Count).Value))) Then
                'MsgBox Count
                'MsgBox UCase(Sheet2.Range("A" & Count).Value)
                    Sheet1.Range("E" & row_num).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                    Sheet1.Range("I" & row_num).Value = "Yes"

                End If

                Count = Count + 1
                'MsgBox Count

            Wend

Loop Until item_sum = ""
```

[image]

As you can see, highlighting works